# What are the technical benefits of these different JSON representations?

Tags: json, rest, unicode, representation

Assuming that you are always using UTF-8, what are the benefits of the JSON representations listed below over the other?

This:

```
{"name": "Kr\u00efst\u00f6f"}
```

Or that:

```
{"name": "Krïstöf"}
```

I'd say that there aren't any differences, except that the latter is more readable to humans and is more lightweight (less bytes).

Or am I missing other benefits here? :-)

Thanks in advance!

K.

Comment: The first is less likely to go wrong across the wire.

Comment: Okay... It may sound like a really stupid question... :-) But how is using ASCII only characters (like the first) more safe for data transfer? (I took CCNA classes once in the past, but that was years ago. :-))

Comment: If you're only sending ASCII across then the encoding is less likely to get messed up. If your software relies on the intermediate transport to have the right encoding set, then that's possible to go wrong (in / out of a database, a broker system, etc). ASCII is common and therefore it's most likely to keep working. You can then convert it before / after sending.

Comment: I see... Valid point! I think I'll use the first method everytime from now on. Thanks!